# twitter-bootstrap embed-responsive not always working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I embedded a youtube video to a page using bootstrap's embed-responsive.  When I resize the browser to fill the left half of my screen the video resizes correctly but when I resize the browser to fill the right-half of my screen or the top half the video doesn't resize and overlaps other content...  Any idea how to fix this/why this is happening?

My code:

I am trying to use bootstrap's responsive-embed to embed a youtube video but for some reason it doesn't show on the page at all.  I know it's on the page as I am using a screenreader which reads it and I can play it and hear the sound but visually it doesn't show at all.
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my code:

screenshots of the resized page:

https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/8N0y4wQ5CwHATxM25UavWLvhrs7%2By5Wv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn out I just had to remove the embed-responsive-item and the col-md-4 from the iframe